# sql to linq conversion for this table

Tags: sql, linq

i need the following result can you help me??

```
City    ||     State       ||     Zip
---------------------------------------
Mayo    ||      FL         ||    234234
Mayo    ||      SC         ||    323455
Mayo    ||      MD         ||    665777
```

```
Select Distinct(City),
       State,
       Max(Zip) As Zip 
from Zipcode 
Group By City,State 
Order By City
```

There can be rows like this enter code here

```
Mayo          MD             665777
Mayo          MD             234566
Mayo          MD             667568
```

But I need to skip and use the max of zip of it.

This query works correct but I want to convert it to linq.

Comment: so do expect someone in SO will convert that for u...

Comment: Note in your Sql, you won't need the `Distinct(City)` given you are also Grouping by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:-

```
var output= countries.GroupBy(c => new { c.State, c.City })
                                  .Select(a => new
                                  {
                                      City = a.Key.City,
                                      State = a.Key.State,
                                      Zip = a.Max(z => z.Zip)
                                  }).OrderBy(m => m.City);
```

Comment: Thaank you very much... This works exactly what i expected... :) :)